# Android show different values after certain time in android textbox

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an android application where in a textbox after certain time we have to show values after certain time. So far I have been able to show only 2 Values. I am also trying to put values in array but so far has been unsuccessful
I am placing my code. Any idea will be helpful. Well there is a button and after I press the button the first value appears on the textbox. which is 62.53. After I click on the buttopn second time I am seeing the other value 72.5. I am willing to show 10 values after I click on the button consecutive 10 times. I am not able to do so..Thats my question

public void onClick(View v) {

```
     if (recording) {

         recorder.stop();

        // recorder.release();

         recording = false;

         Log.d("Test","recorderonclick");

        // Stop Thread

         MobilityMonitorV2.setRunning(false);

         button.setText(R.string.titleStart);

         Log.d("Test","recorderclick");

         // Upload Files to Server

         UploadThread upThread = new UploadThread(

                MobilityMonitorV2.TIMESTAMP, handler);

         upThread.start();

         Log.d("Test","recorderonclick");

        initRecorder();

         setOutputFile(false);

         prepareRecorder();

        Log.d("TEst","recordercick");





        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);



         textView.setText("62.53"); 

        String editTextStr = textView.getText().toString();

         String string = getString(R.string.hello);

        //recorder.reset();

         button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



                       public void onClick(View v) {









                                 textView.setText("72.5");  



                        }

                        });





    }






    else {

         resetRecorder();

        initRecorder();

         setOutputFile(true);

         prepareRecorder();

        recording = true;

         recorder.start();

         Log.d("Test","recorderreset");




        // Start Bluetooth data thread

         DataStream dataStream = new DataStream();

        dataStream.start();

         Log.d("Test","bluetoothdataset");



        button.setText(R.string.titleStop);

         Log.d("Test","buttonsetstop");

        //TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  

         //textView1.setText("62.5");  

    }



 }


            }
```

Comment: can you explain better your question?

Comment: Please post your whole code, something that will compile. That would help everyone to understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Untested!!

```
private TextView textView1;
private static int mCounter = 0;

private ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    // Add the values you would like to show
    values.add("62.53");
    values.add("72.5");
    // etc. etc.

    // Get a reference to your textview
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  

    // Set a click listener
    textView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // Get the value from your arraylist
            String value = values.get(mCounter);

            // Set the value in your textview
            textView1.setText(value);

            // Increase the counter
            mCounter++;
        }
    });
}
```